# I hear a burning sound when I try my built-in flash, and my shutter button doesn't work

Tags: flash, troubleshooting

I can normally take pictures, but when I try the built-in flash, my flash won't fire and shutter won't work. Also sometimes I hear a burning sound from within the camera when I try the flash.

Comment: What camera make and model are you using? Does it _never_ fire the flash and shutter, or just after a period of time between shots? Describe the "burning" sound you hear.

Comment: D800e, used purchased off mpb.com

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

Fire does not really make much of a specific sound so you should better describe what you call a "burning sound".  Crackling and potentially smelling means arcing.  By far the most predominant reason is the flash capacitor having progressive breakthroughs, preventing it from reaching operating voltage and consequently keeping the camera waiting for flash readiness indefinitely while continuing to destroy the capacitor.  Since the resulting fumes can be bad for electronics and the expanding capacitor can cause mechanical damage as well, this is a case for servicing in a timely manner.

Comment: Also, the sounds and smells might be from the inverter or even other parts of the camera power supply being slowly destroyed due to being overloaded....

Comment: @rackandboneman Unlikely since an empty capacitor (the normal use case for the charge circuit) is essentially a short circuit, and a regular discharge through the flash tube is quite a higher load than a dying capacitor.  If the camera can take a series of photographs with flash, it can take frying the capacitor.  The capacitor can do damage other than electrically, of course.

Comment: Yes it's sort of a cracking sound, after a day of shooting without flash today I see that the crackling burning sound is gone, but I can't shoot either when my flash is popped out. No matter what I try, I can't shoot with my flash popped out.